# Saving position/locations of sortable divs using localStorage

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a sortable div setup that will save the layout. I'm clearly doing something wrong in this, or missing something simple. 
The sortable is working correctly, but the saving, and loading isn't working properly. 
When I refresh, everything goes back to original, and it should be saving the layout chosen. I had this somewhat working with the jquery cookie plugin, but I don't wish to use that. 
I'm hoping someone can help me out here. I've looked through a lot of the posts here, but haven't found something that will answer my question, Google was my friend and got me to this point. But now I'm at a loss.

```
$(function() {
  $( '[id^="sortable"]' ).sortable({
    connectWith: '[id^="sortable"]',
    helper: "clone",
    appendTo: ".primary_container",
    update: function() {
        $( '[id^="sortable"]' ).children().each(function(){
            savePosition($(this).attr("id"));
        });
    }
  });
});

function savePosition(id){
  var el = $("#" + id);
  var container = el.parent().attr("id");
  var index = el.index();
  localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify({ container:container, index:index }));
}

function loadPosition(id){
  var el = $("#" + id);
  var position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
  console.log(position);
  var container = "#" + position.container;
  var index = position.index;
  if(index == 0){
    $(container).prepend(el);
  }else if($(container).children().eq(index - 1).length == 0){
    $(container).append(el);
  }else{
    $(container).children().eq(index - 1).after(el);
  }     

}

$( '[id^="sortable"]' ).children().each(function(){
  loadPosition($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wagd0xg0/)

Comment: New working fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/wagd0xg0/2/

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

```
localStorage.setItem('positions', $("#" + id).sortable("toArray") );
```

Needed to be changed to

```
localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify({ container:container, index:index }));
```

And

```
var position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('positions'));
```

changed to

```
var position = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id));
```

Updated post to reflect working changes.